# Handling button touch based on the Observable value

Tags: swift, observable, rx-swift

I wanted to know what is the best practice to handling button tap based on the `Observable`. I've got enum:

```
enum ButtonState {
    case idle, valid, nonValid
}
```

and `Observable` which is combining two Observables:

```
var buttonStateObservable: Observable<ButtonState> {
        return Observable.combineLatest(isAddingVariable.asObservable(), addItemName.asObservable(),
                                        resultSelector: { isAdding, itemName in
                                            if isAdding {
                                                return !itemName.isEmpty ? .valid : .nonValid
                                            }
                                            return .idle
        })
    }
```

In my ViewController I'm subscribing to this observable and updating `UIButton`'s UI. I would like to handle tap on this button and do certain action based on this observable. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RxSwift` already has `ControlEvent` that wrapped `TouchUpInside` event of `UIButton`. You can access it by `.rx.tap`:

```
button.rx.tap.subscribe(onNext: {
    self.button.setTitle("\(arc4random_uniform(100))", for: .normal)
    self.button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.random.cgColor // or your special color
})
.disposed(by: bag)
```

Result of 3 taps:

[image]

---

**UPD.**

You can check other observables by `.withLatestFrom()`. Improved top example:

```
let subject = BehaviorSubject<Bool>(value: true)

button.rx.tap.asDriver()
    .withLatestFrom(subject.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false))
    .drive(onNext: { value in
        if value {
            self.button.setTitle("\(arc4random_uniform(100))", for: .normal)
            self.button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.random().cgColor
        }
        subject.onNext(!value)
    })
    .disposed(by: bag)
```

So, in your case you can put `Observable.combineLatest(...)` in `.withLatestFrom` and perform logic with these values.

Comment: I know, I use it in my code but I didn’t ask about handling but handling and checking the Observable’s condition.

Comment: @codddeer123, does it help you?